# Minor CSS issue

Tags: css, shadow, shadowbox

I am new to the designing/programming world so I am sure the issue is easy to solve.  I am trying to add the moz-box-shadow effect to my header.  But as soon as I add that component, the header which is taking up space horizontally shortens up.  I want the header to be like Twitter's, where they use a shadow effect.

```
#header {
    background-color: #990000;
    width:101.3%;
    margin-left:-8px;
    margin-top:-8px;
    height:40px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #D7D7D7;
}
```

Also, the way i have set the width is it likely going to create cross browser issues?

Comment: It works for me, you might not see the shadow because it is too light, try setting the color to black just for visualization purposes.

Comment: Hey, the shadow is the not the problem, its the width of the header, when i use the shadow effect, the with shortens a bit maybe by like 10%.  Nontheless, its noticeable.

Comment: This: `width:101.3%; margin-left:-8px; margin-top:-8px;` - it looks like you might be *doing it wrong* a little bit :) It will work, but there's probably a more standard way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried with `{ top:0; left:0; width:100%; }` instead of the margins and width=101.3%?

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the HTML with it, can you throw it up on something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not much relevant html.  rest is content being echoed via php

Comment: @AAA: Can you tell me what's wrong with [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ST3q7/)?

Comment: @thitydot The header is not taking up the entire horizontal space.  I guess this page is a good example:  look at thier header, thats what i am tryign to do:    http://twitter.com/login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Here's a version similar to what Twitter has</strike>:
This *is* Twitter's version, more or less:

[***Live Demo***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/n3r2y/show/light/) ([*edit*](http://jsfiddle.net/n3r2y/))

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top-fixed">
    <div id="top-bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0
}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: #c0deed
}
#top-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#top-bar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;

    background-color:#00a0d1;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#00a0d1),to(#008db8));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#00a0d1,#008db8);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00a0d1',endColorstr='#008db8');
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00a0d1',endColorstr='#008db8')";

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!! Is there a way to not make it fixed but still get the same effect.  Like you know how the blue bar still shows when you scroll down, what if you can do it witout it being fixed.

Comment: Sure, just change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` and it won't stay at the top when you scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/n3r2y/1/

Comment: Hey how did u get the gradient effect? Is there a way to get it in 1f1f1f.

Comment: @thirtydot , could you read my answer below and give your opinion?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I am stuck on the generator.  I can't get the gradient for the color i want for #1F1F1F

Comment: @AAA: I don't understand what you want me to make the gradient look like. You only gave one colour (which is very close to black) - you need two colours to make a gradient.

Comment: Something that creates the same effect that is being used in twitters color.... Thabks

Comment: Thanks! just a little bit darker.

Comment: All you have to do is replace all (5) instances of `#565656` in my last demo with a darker colour. Try `#444444`, or whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

The trick that Twitter is using, is putting in an absolutely positioned box and giving that box a width of 100% and the shadow. Using `overflow-x: hidden` on it´s parent, you get the effect that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing shadows with .png's.  I see no benefit of using this (esp. since I would assume browsers started supporting .png prior to supporting box shadows[see, for example, Mozila's statement that FF started supporting box shadows in FF3.5](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/moz-box-shadow/),) but of course, if this is better than doing shadows via .png, feel free to leave a comment proving me wrong!

Comment: You're right that doing the shadows with `.png` files will work almost everywhere, whereas `box-shadow` will only work in newer browsers. However, it's not *vital* that the shadows work in older (rarer) browsers - it's a case of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Also the number of people using newer browsers is going up and up. So for what amounts to minor eye candy, Twitter decided to just stick to `box-shadow`.